# What are the material components for the Enhance Ability spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

The *Player's Handbook* states the components for the [*Enhance Ability*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enhance-ability) spell as being "fur or feather from a beast". Does this mean you need fur from a bear, bull, cat and fox as well as a feather from an eagle and an owl if you want to be able to enhance any ability or do you just need fur or a feather from any animal to cast it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Any fur or feather from any beast. Compare to the spell *creation*.

The material component for *enhance ability* is:

> *fur or a feather from a beast*

No further specificity is given, so no further specificity is needed. Any fur or feather from a beast will work for any of the spell's options. For the spell's particular options to require a particular material component, we would need to have that explained to us in the spell description.

For example, the spell *creation* has different durations depending on what material component you use. The material component is:

> a tiny piece of matter of the same type of the item you plan to create

And the description says:

> The duration depends on the object's material. If the object is composed of multiple materials, use the shortest duration.

So we have an example of a spell referencing its material components and giving a different effect based on what is used. Since we do not have similar explanation given in *enhance ability*, any fur or feather from any beast is appropriate for any of the spell's options.

Alternatively, a spellcasting focus or component pouch can provide the M component for *enhance ability*, since the component os not consumed and has no cost.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that was the cast but since I was likey to need to next session I thought I ought to check. I don't know where I would have got the fur from a cat from if I needed it.

Comment: @RichardYoung: Note that *enhance ability* doesn't consume its material components, nor do they have a specified cost, so the spell's material components can be substituted by a spellcasting focus (if your class can use a focus) or component pouch.